# Problema em gerar um app Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ao tentar criar uma aplicação Ruby On Rails aconteceu isso;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tentei contorna assim;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como resolver isso?

Comment: [OBS] Nada contra, mas aconselho a usar Linux ou Mac para desenvolvimento com RoR.

Answer (score 1):

Parece problema no certificado SSL (acesso https), o windows parece não aceitar o certificado do repositório de gems, por isso não consegue finalizar o bundle install.

Tente uma das duas alternativas:

1) Remova a url segura, e adicione uma URL que não utiliza o ssl (sem httpS).
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/

2) Tente a solução para windows, no fim deste artigo: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html . Um amigo utilizou esta solução e resolveu o problema:

*Solution for Windows
Fletcher Nichol shows how to [download a cacert.pem file](https://gist.github.com/867550) and set an environment variable to install the certificate authorities needed by the OpenSSL library.*

Abraço